# JTabbedPane tab-alignment

Tags: tabs, jtabbedpane, alignment

I can't seem to find this.

What method (and constant) do I use to align the tabs in a `JTabbedPane`.
I Found how to switch between Top and Bottom. But I'm trying to put them in the center at the bottom.
So that it looks like this

ooooooooooooooooooo

o..................................o

o..................................o

o..................................o

o..................................o

ooooooooooooooooooo

......  |Tab1||Tab2|

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This layout rule is enforced by the selected look and feel.

Comment: SO in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZi1x-7jiP4&feature=player_embedded it just works becuz it's on Mac?

Comment: It's running on MacOS. The default look and feel *on MacOS* have the tabs be placed at the center.

Comment: Okay, thanks! too bad it can't be changed. But well Okay then :)

Comment: AFAIK you can always change the look and feel? Not sure how though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own **UI-Delegate** for JTabbedPane component that extends `BasicTabbedPane` class and overwrite the
method '`getTabInsets(int, int)`'. Change value of '`tabInsets`' atribute ( default value is: new Insets(0,4,1,4), centered).